# How to hold values in a component even after the component is unmounted

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic with angular. My target is to hold values in a particular component even after the component is unmounted. I tried with angular input output decorator but it is not working

Comment: create a service and save values in it and then use this service anywhere with its saved values...

Comment: Can I store values in a service without storing the values in localstorage?

Comment: nope these differ, local storage is used to save values to serve u even if u close the app while inside a service, it serves you while app is running, so for example u are in page a and you need to go to page b then u save the values inside the service while inside page a and when u go to page b and call the service and get the values, but in real life examples, if u need to use a storage (local storage works in this case but is not secured), then its used inside a service so u can set and get values easily inside your app and saving them at the same time and still this merge depends on app.